# angular material theming: consume the theme definition object in another scss file

Tags: angular, angular-material2, theming

I am coding in Angular 4.3.6 using @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.10

[Angular Material Document](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme) says

> If you want to consume the theme definition object (e.g.,
>   $candy-app-theme) in other SCSS files, then the definition of the
>   theme object should be broken into its own file, separate from the
>   inclusion of the mat-core and angular-material-theme mixins.

How do I archive it? To be specific, I have the following in my top level scss:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Include non-theme styles for core.
@include mat-core();
$primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo, 400, 100, 900);
```

how do I make $primary available in other scss files?

In the past, I @include mat-core() everywhere. It is just recenlty that I noticed that

> This should only be included once in your application.

What should be done so that I can map-get($primary) in other scss files?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by trial.

Just follow the instructions to the letter and do nothing else: do not `@include` the `mat-core()` at any other location other than the topmost scss.

You are allowed to `@import` the `~@angular/material/theming` multiple times.
In each scss script you need `mat-palette` or `$mat-indigo`, `@import` it again.

```
// on other scss other than the root one, @import as usual
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// @include mat-core(); but don't @include this again
$primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo, 400, 100, 900);
```